# Setting sound output/input

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, audio

I've been looking all over the web, but I don't know if it is possible: can a Cocoa Mac OS X app change the sound input/output device? If so, how come?

Answer (score 2):

> can a Cocoa Mac OS X app change the sound input/output device?

Yes, by [setting](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CACoreAudioReference/AudioHardware/CompositePage.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioHardwareSetProperty) the [relevant Audio System Object property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CACoreAudioReference/AudioHardware/CompositePage.html#//apple_ref/doc/title%3atag/AudioSystemObjectProperties).

> If so, how come?

Probably because the user might want to change the default input or output device from within an application, rather than having to jump over to the Sound prefpane before and after or use the Sound menu extra.

Comment: I didn't know the sound Menu Extra could change the input/output devices. How can I enable that?

Comment: Jailborc: Hold down the Option key when you click on it.

Comment: Damn. That's awesome to know. Not very discoverable at all. Should probably be there all the time...

Comment: Unfortunately the links are broken. :(

Comment: @uchuugaka: Please file a Radar.

Comment: Which one, or for both?

Comment: @uchuugaka Generally, every page that's missing. Both of the links in my answer are to (different parts of) the same page.

Comment: Ok will do after the holidays

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I've been struggling these days trying to find a way of changing the sound input/output device using code and I finally found how to do it. In case someone else runs into the same problem, here's the answer!

There's a command line utility called SwitchAudio-OSX (https://code.google.com/p/switchaudio-osx/) that allows you to switch the audio source from the terminal. It is open-source and you can find the latest version here: https://github.com/deweller/switchaudio-osx.

Anyway, you can use these lines to change the sound input/output device:

```
UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(UInt32);
AudioHardwareSetProperty(kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultInputDevice, propertySize, &newDeviceID); // To change the input device
AudioHardwareSetProperty(kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice, propertySize, &newDeviceID); // To change the output device
AudioHardwareSetProperty(kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultSystemOutputDevice, propertySize, &newDeviceID); // To change the system output device
```

Where `newDeviceID` is an instance of `AudioDeviceID` and represents the id of the device you want to select. Also, a list of all available devices can be obtained using this code:

```
AudioDeviceID dev_array[64];
AudioHardwareGetProperty(kAudioHardwarePropertyDevices, &propertySize, dev_array);
int numberOfDevices = (propertySize / sizeof(AudioDeviceID));
```